# AngularJS ngResrouce REST Authentication

Tags: rest, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to learn AngularJS.  I'm try to make a simple authenticated get request to a REST api.  At this point, i'm just trying to get a response back. I keep getting invalid key because I can't seem to send the headers properly.

```
angular.module('App', ['ngResource']);

function AppCtrl($scope, $resource){
$scope.app = $resource('https://theapiurl.com/parameter=:action',
    {action:'My Parameter works fine!'}, 
    {method: 'GET'},
    {headers: 'auth-key' : 'key'});
$scope.app.get();
}
```

I just can't seem to get the header to send.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: What authorisation scheme is using `theapiurl.com`?

Comment: Im really not sure how to answer that.  The api and key are provided by mashape.com.  This doc describes how they authenticate. https://www.mashape.com/docs/consume/rest#authorization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using angular-resource 1.1.x+ the following should work:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngResource']);

function AppCtrl($scope, $resource){
    $scope.app = $resource('https://theapiurl.com/parameter=:action',
      {
        action:'My Parameter works fine!'
      }, 
      {
        get: {
          method: 'GET',
          headers : { 'auth-key' : 'key' }
        }
      });
     $scope.app.get();
}
```

If you are using 1.0.x branch this won't work. I believe the only alternative is to set global default headers in $httpProvider, or to user $http directly (not using $resource). Here's how you would set the headers globally:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['auth-key'] = 'key';
```

Comment: I had missed one thing in my answer. I updated it to show the correct way. Note this will only work in 1.1.x and above.

Comment: Excellent.  I switched to version 1.1.5 from 1.0.7 and added the `get` action and it works as intended!  Though, You have an extra curly brace I believe.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid setting the header in every resource you could use an interceptor:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
            config.headers['auth-key'] = 'key';
                return $q.when(config);
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need interceptors just to set default headers. there is an $httpProvider.defaults.header property just for that purpose.

Comment: This is a better approach if you're using third-party resources as well since you can define conditions.